# image resizing tinymce how to?

Tags: php, image, autoresize, tinymce-4, justboil.me

in a php page, I have implemented the famous tinymce, and I have been using this plugin (http://justboil.me/) for uploading images.
For example, if you load a picture with width 1024 this will be printed in the textarea width with 1024.
How do I auto-resize the image to 600px?

Comment: I havent used this yet but at the config.php on line 79, there is a set able value that could help you. (`$config['max_width']`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem.
It worked for me after I set the

`$config['max_width'] = 600;`

**AND** also

`$config['max_height'] = 600;`

in the **config.php** file

**Note:** You have to set **both** values to get the resize working. Even if you dont need to set the height, if one of the values is set to 0, nothing will be resized.

I found this information [here.](http://browse.feedreader.com/c/JustBoil_me_TinyMCE_Images_Plugin/396151239)

Comment: Thanks man!   
I changed $config['max_width'] = 600; only.
 :)